# python BeautifulSoup how get values between tags?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My html structure is:

```html
<div class="layout4-background">
    <h6 class="game">Game1. How to get all listings below and assign to class"game"?</h6>
    <ul>
        <li class="listing">
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="listing">
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="listing">
    </ul>
    <h6 class="game">Game2. How to get all listings below and assign to class"game?</h6>
    <ul>
        <li class="listing">
    </ul>
    <h6 class="game">Game3. How to get all listings below and assign to class"game?</h6>
    <ul>
        <li class="listing">
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's a one div block. Basically I need to create a list of each h6 class. the first h6 - 3 listings, the second h6 - 1 listing, the third h6 - 1 listing. Is there a way to do it with BeautifulSoup?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the result of [`.find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) that are `<ul>` elements:

```
from itertools import takewhile, ifilter

div = soup.find('div', class_='layout4-background')
for header in div.find_all('h6'):
    print header.get_text()
    listings = takewhile(lambda t: t.name == 'ul',
                         header.find_next_siblings(text=False))
    for listing in listings:
        # do something with listing
```

The `find_next_siblings()` search finds all nodes that are not just text nodes (skipping whitespace in between).
The [`itertools.takewhile()` iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) lets you pick *just* the next elements that are all `<ul>` tags.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div class="layout4-background">
...     <h6 class="game">Game1. How to get all listings below and assign to class"game"?</h6>
...     <ul>
...         <li class="listing">
...     </ul>
...     <ul>
...         <li class="listing">
...     </ul>
...     <ul>
...         <li class="listing">
...     </ul>
...     <h6 class="game">Game2. How to get all listings below and assign to class"game?</h6>
...     <ul>
...         <li class="listing">
...     </ul>
...     <h6 class="game">Game3. How to get all listings below and assign to class"game?</h6>
...     <ul>
...         <li class="listing">
...     </ul>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> div = soup.find('div', class_='layout4-background')
>>> for header in div.find_all('h6'):
...     print header.get_text()
...     listings = takewhile(lambda t: t.name == 'ul',
...                          header.find_next_siblings(text=False))
...     print 'Listings found:', len(list(listings))
... 
Game1. How to get all listings below and assign to class"game"?
Listings found: 3
Game2. How to get all listings below and assign to class"game?
Listings found: 1
Game3. How to get all listings below and assign to class"game?
Listings found: 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it is a silly question. But how to create something like this new = {}

Comment: @user2745454: not sure what you mean; you want to have a dictionary with what, exactly?

Comment: I forgot to finish my comment. Maybe it is a silly question, but how can I to connect(or merge) these 3 listings into one? for example if len(list(listings)) > 1: do_merge

Comment: What does merging mean here? What is contained in these lists, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: for example each "ul" contains some "button" classes which i need. If there is only one "ul" below "h6" it contains a table of "buttons", i just run the function "get_info_from_the_buttons". If there are more than 1 "ul" below h6, there is no table and I would like to join all "ul" below h6 to one and run "get_info_from_the_buttons".

Comment: result should be {h6_1:[buttons_from ul1+ul2+ ul3], h6_2:[buttons_from_ul1], h6_3:[buttons_from_ul1]

Comment: @user2745454: if that function returns a list, why not just extend your list with the each next set of buttons then?

Comment: Yes, I did it. And it seems works as expected. Thank you for your helpl